# Export SQL Record into .csv using sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, cmd, sqlcmd

I'm trying to export a dataset from SQL with SQLCMD to a .csv file.
The field I'm filtering has the Format e.g. "490658" (Yes, with quotation marks)

In my .cmd file the SqlString looks like

```
set SqlString=Set NOCOUNT ON;SELECT * FROM A_DPD_Print_Manuell WHERE (mpscref1 = '"%1%"')
```

this

And the sqlcmd like this

```
sqlcmd -S XXX -U XXX -P OXXX -d XXX -s "," -Q  "%SqlString%" -W -o  "%Datei1Pfad%"
```

But it returns the error: No closing quote after the string
(Google translator im sorry if its very wrong)

I don't know how to handle this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out.

In the SQL String I needed to add more `"` because the cmd thought the command stops at the first `"`.

So the sqlcmd string was like

```
sqlcmd -S XXX -U XXX -P OXXX -d XXX -s "," -Q "SqlString=Set NOCOUNT ON;SELECT * FROM A_DPD_Print_Manuell WHERE (mpscref1 = '" [...]
```

I just added `mpscref1 = '""%1%""'`

To the sql string and it worked.

Comment: Even though you seem to have gotten it to work, I believe you should be using `'""%1""'`